# SetErrorMode and /MDd (/MTd) compile flag

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I need to prevent the default message box from Visual Studio Debugger to show up during a Heap corruption. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it should be a simple as:

```
SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS | SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX);
```

However I cannot get the above to work. Here is my small toy example:

```
$ cat hc.cxx
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
  SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS | SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX);
  char * p = new char[10];
  for( int i = 0; i < 500; ++i ) p[i] = i;
  delete p;
  return 0;
}
```

If I compile it with no flag, everything goes as expected (no message box):

```
$ cl hc.cxx
```

However if I decide to use /MDd, then the annoying message box comes back:

```
$ cl /MDd hc.cxx
```

Same issue with /MTd.

My system is a Windows Vista Pro/32bits with SP2 installed. Compiler is Visual Studio 2010, and cl version is 16.00.40219.01. SetThreadErrorMode is not available on my system.

In case this helps to understand the issue: I am using CMake+CTest for automated testing. CTest is the parent process (calling [SetErrorMode](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/ctest.html#opt%3a--interactive-debug-mode01)) which execute the test. The tests are then submitted to CDash (equivalent of jenkins/hudson). However if the message box for heap corruption appears the test is flagged as taking too long to execute, instead of nicely reporting a low level issue. I have no control over the user compilation flag, and just need a way to prevent the message box to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking into how to disable/suppress modal dialog like this:

[image]

Then you need to block C++ runtime messaging rather than OS crash reporting. [`_CrtSetReportMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y71x448.aspx) is what you need:

```
#include <crtdbg.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS | SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
```

You still have the report, but this time in debug output, non-blocking:

```
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgheap.c(1322) : Assertion failed: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)
HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#161) at 0x002D2448.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.
HEAP[ConsoleApplication11.exe]: Heap block at 002D2420 modified at 002D2456 past requested size of 2e
ConsoleApplication11.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
HEAP[ConsoleApplication11.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 002D0000, 002D2428 )
ConsoleApplication11.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```